# CSS hover upon a link to fill background

Tags: html, css

What I want:

When I hover upon a link it should fill the background with a fixed width (say 225 pixels) background color.
The length of the text of the link should not be considered.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a:hover {background: url('some225pxWideImage.jpg') no-repeat;}
```

Comment: Actually, you should probably use "repeat-y" then you only need a 1px high image and it will scale no matter the height of your anchor

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<a class="someclass">Some link</a>
```

CSS:

```
a.someclass {
    display: block;
    width: 225px;
}

a.someclass:hover {
    background-color: #123456;
}
```